# Replacing a center door handle

Tags: doors

I've looked everywhere and cant find a replacement for a center door handle am I out of luck do they not make these anymore?[image: Pic of the handle]

Comment: It looks like it has a key hole so guessing it works the latch.  Not a common setup so guessing you need a specially shop that deals with them.  Not even sure where to start looking, maybe a door maker might have an idea.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind having the knob in the center?    I have a feeling that the knob is there, but the only thing that keeps the door closed is the deadbolt.  Unlock the deadbolt and push the door open.  Replace the knob with any .

Comment: If you replaced the knob and used the existing latch assembly, would that work? In that case, you just need to find a new knob that has a matching spindle. (Knowing the brand and seeing a pic of the knob disassembled would help.)

Comment: @RMDman  From a fast search a lot of it is a design statement to stand out.  I think there is a key hole on that knob, so also works a latch.  Just the knob should be an easy fix, if replacing the latch, oh-oh.

Comment: @crip659, I have found nothing that shows a center knob works a latch.  If it does it must be some type of Rube Goldberg set up.  The knob also looks like a standard knob that someone put in the center to make a design statement.  This will be simply answered if the OP tell us if the knob works a latch.

Answer (score 1):

Research shows that [Center door knobs](https://www.simplydoorhandles.co.uk/external-centre-door-knobs#/pageSize=48&orderBy=0&pageNumber=2) are decorative.

Use a search engine to look for "center door knobs".

To remove the one you have, remove the screws that are on the inside of the door.

Comment: Yes the door handle does work if I unlock the dead bolt an lock that handle the door will stay locked. Not sure why the handle was installed this way home was built in 1963 so I'm assuming it was put in then. Ill disassemble it and post pics

Comment: Must have some kind of extension rod to the striker.  Must have been fun to drill *that* hole!

Comment: It is simply a knob with a really long deadbolt extension. I have seen only ones that are readily available at 5" long online.